# How can I have internet access through ssh

Tags: networking, openssh

I have a HP Pavillion 15 with Ubuntu 18.04, `openssh-server` installed and running and I also have an Aspire S3 with Ubuntu 18.04 `openssh-client` installed.

I can access the HP through `ssh` on my Acer Aspire S3, but the problem is that my Internet cable is plugged to my Acer S3.

My question is:
how can I access the internet on `ssh`?

When I do `ssh name@ip_address`, I can connect, but I still have no Internet access...

What can I do?